# Запятая перед "от меня"

Tags: пунктуация

Ваши выгоды:

- 100% соответствие ТЗ. Вы получаете полную отчетность от меня.
- Довожу проект до результата. Помогаю в доработке проекта, даже после сдачи.

Скажите, пожалуйста, здесь нужна запятая перед "от меня"?

Comment: Реклама от первого лица? Лучше назвать себя исполнителем, разработчиком, дизайнером, автором, и пр.

Answer (score 1):

Никаких оснований для постановки запятой тут нет.

Answer (score 1):

Порядок слов здесь нестандартный (ср.: *Вы получаете от меня полную отчетность*), и запятая его не выправит. Лучше **тире** поставить: оно способно заместить опущенные связующие слова.

> Вы получаете полную отчетность **-** [, получаете её] от меня.